# Make the dynamic system associated with the differential equation $x'=t(x^2-1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to make the dynamic system associated with this differential equation by its phase space.It is a simple differential equation since it has separate variables.In class we have seen how to build a dynamic system from an autonomous differential equation And it is clearly seen that this equation is not autonomous. I have tried to proceed in the same way as if I were autonomous but it doesn't work.
Could someone give me a clue to solve this exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(u,v) = (t,x)$, then we have the system
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{u} &= 1 \\
\dot{v} &= u(v^2-1).
\end{aligned}
$$

We can then use a [phase plane plotter](https://aeb019.hosted.uark.edu/pplane.html)  to visualize the $uv$-plane. Alternatively, we could do this by hand by plotting vectors with horizontal component $1$ and vertical component $t(x^2-1)$ in the $tx$-plane.

[image]